# Passing Url Through the Button

Tags: url, button

I am using a simple html button to submit the data.I am using codeigniter framework.The following code is my button for cacel the page and go back to the previous page.

```
<input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="" class="cancel_button">
```

When I click the cancel button it should go to the following url

```
http://localhost/sample/categorycontroller/index
```

Please let me know,how to pass the url through the button.?

Thanks in advance

Comment: onclick="history.go(-1);" ??? just to go to previous page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please user this :

```
 <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="window.location.href = 'http://localhost/sample/categorycontroller/index'" class="cancel_button">
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="window.location = 'http://localhost/sample/categorycontroller/index'" class="cancel_button">
```

Comment: Thanks@Lidor..It is worked perfectly..thanks for looking my question and for the answer..Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="goBack()" class="cancel_button">
```

Then create a Javascript function called `goBack()`

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function goBack() {
    window.location = 'http://localhost/sample/categorycontroller/index';
}

</script>
```